# Joining an ArcGIS Enterprise Database to another SQL database

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, database, arcgis-10.5

I'm curious if it is possible to join an ArcGIS enterprise database to a separate SQL Server. My intention is to have 1 unique attribute on the ArcGIS layer that can reference the row in the SQL table for the join.

Is this possible? I want to be able to drop points in ArcGIS portal, give them a job number and then have it pull the rest of the data associated with that job number into the ArcGIS layer table so I can utilize this data in some sort of datadriven setup.

Comment: How critical is performance?  Joins to linked servers can do this, but are often slow. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752558/125400  This is probably better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server

Comment: Joins across databases are possible but slow. Joins across servers are possible, but extremely slow. Neither has anything to do  Esri software. At the 80,000 foot view, what you want to do is possible, but you'd need to spend  a great deal more time planning details before you have a GIS SE ready question.

Comment: @Vince would a join within ArcMap do the trick? I'm waiting on getting a read-only user for the second database to give this a shot.

Comment: How important is it to see joined table view in arcmap?  If you can live without that, you can still integrate job history using the Identify tool.  Do this by adding the table to the TOC, then set up a one-to-many relate to it   from your job points layer.  The performance can be tolerable. (I think arcpro, with its async-friendly UI, might provide a better experience too.)

Comment: @KirkKuykendall so what I want to do is bring in a PDF and throw dynamic text over the fields I want automatically filled out with the data. The bottom of the finished product will have a location map. I already do this for some other projects but its all within the same ESRI database. The idea is to just have to place a point at job site location in portal with an identifying job # and when requested I can mass run these sheets to fill out the form with data from the 2nd database and a location map with the point from the arcgis server.

Comment: I would use a [REST GET request](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Query_Map_Service_Layer/02r3000000p1000000/) to a table that has been published as part of a mapservice.  But that's quite different from what your question is asking.  Maybe reformulate your question to get better responses.